# side by side banner code

Tags: html

i have a side by side banner code ,the work fine on Firefox.IE,opera,. but not work on google chrome how do i solved this problem ?

```
<table border="0" width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td>my Banner</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: First of all, clarify what you mean by "does not work". Also, clarify what you expect "working" to mean. With screenshots if possible.

Comment: Banner is a layout element. Tables are not to be used for layouts. Try using CSS for layouts.

Comment: shamittomar can send you image via PM ?

Answer (score 0):

Take them out of the table, and use CSS to `float:left;`each banner, inside a container div. As long as their width allows it, they should line up side by side, in Chrome as well.

using your example:

```
    <div id='container'>
<img src='banner1.png' style='float:left;' />
<img src='banner2.png' style='float:left;' /></div>
```

The best way would be to use a .css stylesheet and a banner class to separate your html from your css, but this is just an example to get you started :)

EDIT: I don't use inline javascript really, ever..so this is just a guess if you can do this or not, but it's worth a try.

```
<div id='container'><span style='float:left;'>
<script language='JavaScript' type='text/javascript' 
src='zarclick.ir/banner.php? uname=pitgo&type=2&rows=1' >
</script></span><span style='float:left;'><script language='JavaScript' 
type='text/javascript' src='zarclick.ir/banner.php? uname=pitgo&type=2&rows=1' 
></script></span></div>
```

Might work, I'd try it if I needed to do it.

Comment: Not understand please explain

Comment: gave some example code to make it clearer. When you use `float:left;` it causes the 'floating' object to move all the way to the left, and if there's one to the left of it, the second floats all the way to the left, but only as far as the right margin of the first object, and so on. They will remain side by side until there is no more room in the width of the container and they move down to the next 'line'.

Comment: Dear Elq,my banner code is ==> <script language='JavaScript' type='text/javascript' 

src='http://www.zarclick.ir/banner.php?

uname=pitgo&type=2&rows=1' ></script> i set this banner on chat.tpl.html

Comment: sorry, not sure what you mean. Is this what runs when you click the banner? If so, then it would become the href element of the anchor tag you would surround your banner image with. Or use the onclick event.

Comment: is a banner ads, the question is i have only on google chrome browser problem on another browse work fine,this side by side

Comment: how I've style the img tags in the example is just to show how to do it. You can style most any element with float:left;. So, whatever you are using for your actual visual banner, that's what you place inside your container div and style with float:left;   Yes, this will work in the other browsers as well.

Comment: google chrome http://s3.directupload.net/images/110120/eaorb5gb.jpg    opera ==> http://s5.directupload.net/images/110120/ih2d8qgp.jpg

Comment: that's what you wanted, right? Altho, it looks as if it's still in a table. but they are side by side. If you put them in a div, they should move closer together because you don't have the styling of the table to deal with.

Comment: yes ,i want the banner appear same opera side by side ,. why is not possible on google chrome ?!!!!

Comment: it is..did you try using the example I gave?

Comment: if yoy this code mean ,yes not appear banner ==> <div id='container'>
<img src='banner1.png' style='float:left;' />
<img src='banner2.png' style='float:left;' /></div>

Comment: the img tags were just an example, because I don't know what object element you are using on the page. I edited the above code, try it.

Comment: sorry not work,, I change this code  <table border="0" width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td>my Banner</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
</table>  to this code then now work fine ==> <center>
<table cellspacing=5 cellpadding=0 border=0>
<tr>
<td> First banner code here </td>
<td> Second banner code here </td>
</tr>
</table>
</center>

Comment: well, it's not semantically correct, nor is it helpful as far as accessibility, but if it works, it works. At least you got the result you were looking for.

Comment: you are right, that changes nothing,with your code still not appear side by side, my banner code was wrong ==> banner code is ==><!-- Begin OxinAds.Com Banner Code --> <script 

type="text/javascript" 

src="http://www.oxincode.com/showbanneri.php?

a=MQ==&bs=Nw==&s=NDY4eDYw&c=5f615f&u=33507&row=1&c

ol=1&text=1"></script>  <!-- End OxinAds.Com Banner Code --

>

Answer (score 0):

You should read this tutorial on how to create tableless layouts as this is the standard used for web 2.0 pages. You should always seperate the content from the layout in your web page, which means that your HTML file/s should only display the content, while the CSS file/s will contain the layout, and the JS file/s will contain the HTML manipulation scripts.

http://webdesign.about.com/od/css/a/aa102102a.htm

Comment: You should use float:left to style elements side by side. Set the width to both banners and set them both to float:left. This should solve your problem.